# MVC with SharePoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, configuration, web-config

1. We are looking to use the MVC Framework in our SP Application.
2. This is what we are trying to accomplish...
   A virtual directory within the SPSite which can host and run MVC.
   for e.g., /_layouts/MVC/

Any hints on the required configuration changes (if at all this is possible) will be very helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might be of interest to you
http://www.codeplex.com/SharePointMVC

I published it about 5 minutes ago.

It is basically a library to help rendering ASP.MVC inside a SharePoint masterpage.

Still early days but you get the idea.

Comment: Does this work with the latest Sharepoint Foundation 2010 as well? Is this project still in progress or is it a thing of the past...

Comment: Robert
Unfortunatly I have not been working on any projects involving sharepoint 2010 and hence have not updated the code base. Fee free to submit a patch.

Answer (score 4):

You're going to have a hoot of a time de-inheriting everything (modules, handlers, assemblies, namespaces) in the MVC app's web.config. I would recommend that instead of trying to get MVC working inside of the same IIS web site, why not just run your app outside of SharePoint? Joel Oleson just blogged about using "widgets" or "web parts" as a form of SharePoint integration:

[Joel Oleson](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=109)

Answer (score 3):

I have heard from the MS MVC team that there is no plans for Sharepoint to use MVC. However MVC can be used with Sharepoint with a few tweaks

The following sharepoint site, www.themedicinecabinet.co.uk, was built using ASP.net MVC 2.

This article explains how this was done
http://vspug.com/mbailey/files/2010/04/Using-ASP.NET-MVC-2-with-Sharepoint-Publishing.pdf

Answer (score 1):

We've just released an opensource project that let's you use SharePoint 2010 as the backend of a site and use ASP.NET MVC3 on the frontend.  We've been using the code base for the last two years and wanted to share it with the community since we're confident others would find it useful.

Documentation is still sparse - please feel free to reach out if you have any questions or need help.

http://www.slamcms.com

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running your virtual directory in it's own app pool.  I'm leveraging MVC on some other Microsoft products and the app pool's Managed Pipeline Mode must = 'Integrated' for MVC.