# SharePoint and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

Has anyone had any success with SharePoint and MVC, are Microsoft going to support this going forward in 2010?

Comment: see comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192712/mvc-with-sharepoint (duplicate question?)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry my friend. SharePoint 2013 which is the next version of SharePoint will not support MVC. SharePoint as an technology is entirely based on web forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both technologies (SharePoint and MVC). I allready display information from sharepoint in a portal based on MVC. This worked really good. But there will no support out of the box. Because for developing SharePoint Solutions, Microsoft provides own templates (e.g. WebParts, ControlTemplates, Workflows... ).

So if you want to use both you have to work with the SharePoint API. Some informations you can find here:

[www.msscorner.de](http://www.msscorner.de)

I hope this post will help you!

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.